# Manage two voice modems in C#

Tags: c#, modem, dialing

I need information how to link two voice modems to each other.
From modem 1 I dial and play a .wav file
then I dial modem 2 and link them to allow them speak.

What do I need to link two modems in C#, is it technically possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Are they connected to the public phone system?

Comment: Yes, one conected to Phone Line, and another is a GSM modem, for cell phones

Comment: I need to make a phone call through phone line modem to a number A, then after playing voice file, i must dial through GSM modem and link each other to allow them talk writing all the conversation to a file. Is that possible? any comments?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, but it will require a fair bit of work.

1. You need to send commands to the modem to lift, make the call etc. You can do this through AT commands, and the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` class. This bit is fairly standard, and i'm sure you can find an example/lib out there that will handle all this at a higher level than AT commands.
2. To link the voice part of the modems will depend on the exact modem. Most modems will install an audio component for the OS. If yours do, then what you need to do, is use directX to read/write to the specific audio devices.

What you're building here is a simple voice switch of sorts, and they do require a bit of work. Good luck.